# openvpn keep connection alive on client down?

Tags: server, tcp, udp, connection, openvpn

My internet is randomly dropping for 1 or 2 seconds, which is enough for me to get disconnected from online matches.

Is it possible to configure an openvpn so that the connection somehow remains responsive to the server while my connection is offline?